# Capturar el evento de varios botones según la clase

Tags: html, jquery, html5, datatables, jquery-ui

Tengo un datatable donde genero un formatter que genera varios botones por cada ROW de esta celda, la idea es capturar el evento CLICK en cada botón marcando-lo como si fueran de la clase **btn-change-status**

```
<td style="">
    <a href="#" class="btn-change-status" data-id="1" data-status="1" style="color:black">
          <span style="font-size: 1em; color: lawngreen;">
              <i class="btn-change-status fas fa-check-square fa-2x" title="Cambiar estado a aceptado">
              </i>
          </span>
     </a>
</td>
```

El problema lo tengo en capturar el evento de dicho botón, he probado de esta manera

```
<script>
$(".btn-change-status").on("click", function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('test1');
});

$(".btn-change-status").click( function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('test2');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ese `<td>` que nos muestras entiendo que lo generas dinamicamente y que no se encuentra creado de inicio en el **DOM**. ¿Correcto?

Comment: exacto @phpMyGuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te está sucediendo es que en el momento de asignarle a los elementos `.btn-change-status` el evento **click**, al no encontrarse estos todavía creados en el **DOM** no lo están recibiendo.

Para evitar esto puedes vincularle el evento al **document** y a través del segundo parámetro (que es opcional) de la función `on()` decir que elemento quieres que lo dispare.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td style="">
    <a href="#" class="btn-change-status" data-id="1" data-status="1" style="color:black">
          <span style="font-size: 1em; color: lawngreen;">
              <i class="btn-change-status fas fa-check-square fa-2x" title="Cambiar estado a aceptado">
              </i>
              Pulsa
          </span>
     </a>
</td>

<script>
$(document).on("click", '.btn-change-status',  function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('test1');
});
</script>
```

De esta manera, como el evento lo tiene el **document** siempre lo vas a tener disponible y en el momento en que el elemento pulsado sea el de la clase deseada se va a poder llamar sin ningún problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, lo he entendido y ya me funciona. 1000 gracias por todo !!!!!!!!